# How should a file be encrypted?

Tags: windows, encryption

I was trying to encrypt a file with:

> cipher /E file.txt

However when I move the file to another system it's not encrypted.

Maybe I miss something in the execution of the command ?

Comment: Depends on what  you need.  Cipher sets a file to use [EFS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/298009/cipher.exe-security-tool-for-the-encrypting-file-system).  As you found, that applies only to your local system.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about a password protected file. I will try to follow the guide here : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722147%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you could use GPG for this. for windows you can follow a tutorial just like this one:

- https://www.deepdotweb.com/2015/02/21/pgp-tutorial-for-windows-kleopatra-gpg4win/

which will explain everything step by step.

Comment: the keys are the most important part of this, private keys are secret, public keys you can hand out. if you and your friend both install gpg, you can exchange public keys and import them for each other. that way you can encrypt something only for him to decrypt and visa versa. if you move computers entirely you **must** take the keys with you. that's where the exporting feature comes in.